# Android Gradle Build: duplicate entry: META-INF/app_release.kotlin_module

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying to build a release app via Android Studio > Generate Signed Bundle or APK > Android App Bundle > Release

However gradle fails with

```
: > Task :core:transformClassesWithMergeClassesForRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':core:transformClassesWithMergeClassesForRelease'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: META-INF/app_release.kotlin_module
```

In my `build.gradle` I've tried adding:

```
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/app_release.kotlin_module'
    }
```

But it isn't making any difference whatsoever.

How do I fix this?

For extra context, it's a multi module project.

I have a `core` module, and an `installed` module which is declared in the `core` `build.gradle` with `dynamicFeatures = [":installed"]`

Thanks

Comment: sorry for annoying tip: try running Clean Project

Answer (score 4):

Please make sure all your dependencies are `api` or `implementation`,
I have the flowing dependency grap.

meemo_sdk:
***api*** project(":gvoice")

app project:
implementation project(":gvoice")
implementation project("meemo_sdk")

It complains "META-INF/gvoice_debug.kotlin_module" collision.
After change api to implementation, it works!

Comment: Changing the api to implementation worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

So I figured it out.

I pressed shift twice in Android studio (to open up the search everywhere dialog) and searched for `app_release.kotlin_module`

I saw two files, that were under two of my dependencies (which funnily enough were libraries that I had created!)

I opened up these library projects, and in the `build.gradle` file I had to add:

```
ext {
    PUBLISH_GROUP_ID = 'com.companyname'
    PUBLISH_ARTIFACT_ID = 'packagename'
}

android {
    ...
    compileOptions {
            kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs += ['-module-name', "$PUBLISH_GROUP_ID.$PUBLISH_ARTIFACT_ID"]
    }
}
```

Rebuilt the library projects with new versions, used these new versions in my other project, and it started compiling :)

Answer (score 2):

`Build -> Clean Project` Worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I found the same issue comes randomly by using Android Studio 4.2.1 and Java8, I sorted out successfully by deleting `.gradle` file in the project (not the main one) every time I get the error.

```
Java version: JDK8221
Kotlin: 1.5.0
AndroidStudio: 4.2.1
```

Not the best solution but is a good workaround for now.